# Perl run subroutine on different host

Tags: perl

i am new in perl. I have script where i need to jump to different hosts and comparing FS, environments etc

I have one main jumpserver(MAIN_JUMP and 5 jumpservers to different clusters(CLUSTER_JUMP_1-5). I run my script on MAIN_JUMP, but i need run some subroutines on CLUSTER_JUMP_*. In subroutine I jump to specific host in cluster.

Is it possible to run subroutine via ssh or some perl modules directly on CLUSTER_JUMP? for now I use double ssh to CLUSTER_JUMP_* and then to specific host. It is working in some cases, but for example selects to oracle databases is not working due to quote marks.

Comment: Are you looking for a perl [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) module?

Comment: https://www.rexify.org/

Comment: Yes something like this. I think there is possibility create a main script and this subroutines rewrite as small scripts. But i hope there is simpler solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

[Object::Remote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Remote) will do this for you in a really easy way...

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Object::Remote;

####################################################################
# Note that My::File must be installed on the machines you want to
# run this on!
####################################################################
# package My::File;
# use Moo;
# has path => ( is => 'ro', required => 1 );
# sub size {
#   my $self = shift;
#   -s $self->path;
# }
# 1;
####################################################################

use My::File;

## find the size of a local file
my $file1 = My::File->new( path => '/etc/hostname' );
say $file1->size;

## find the size of a file on a remote host
my $conn  = Object::Remote->connect('host.example.net');  # ssh 
my $file2 = My::File->new::on( $conn, path => '/etc/hostname' );
say $file2->size;
```

**Update:** for clarity, there's nothing special about "My::File". That's just an example of a module that you would write and ensure is installed properly on all the machines that you will be remotely accessing, plus the "client" machine. It can be any module written in an OO style.